# Is there is any plugin to parse csv files send to backend for grails 3.1.1?

Tags: csv, parsing, grails

I had send an csv file using an curl command to my backend build using grails 3.1.1 And I am able to get file in multipart . Now i want to access that file and want to update my database based on the information in that csv file. So is there is any plugin to parse these type of file for grails 3.1.1 and if there is not any such plugin then can somebody have sample groovy code to parse such file. I had tried but i had been failed to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use https://bintray.com/sachinverma/plugins/org.grails.plugins:csv
It's not obvious how to get the plugin for a grails 3 project from the docs there so add the following to build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    https://bintray.com/sachinverma/plugins/org.grails.plugins:csv
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:csv:1+"
}
```

Then use like:

```
def is
try {
    def file = params.csvfile
    is = file.getInputStream()
    is.toCsvReader().eachLine { tokens ->
        do stuff with tokens
    }
...
```

or

```
def is 
try {   
    is = params.csvfile.getInputStream()   
    def csvMapReader = new CSVMapReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) )   
    csvMapReader.fieldKeys = ["field1","field2"]
    csvMapReader.eachWithIndex { map, idx ->
        do stuff with map
    }
...
```

Comment: I am not being able to import CSVMapReader class

Comment: I am using the same (?) plugin but without the bintray repository entry. Simply added `compile 'org.grails.plugins:csv:1.0'` to build.gradle. @AjayShah you may have to clean your project and/or refresh dependencies.